# How to implement Sine PWM using Tiva TM4C123G?

Tags: c, microcontroller, pwm

I am trying to implement the SPWM (Sine PWM) using the TM4C123G Microcontroller.

I tried to do the same thing using another microcontroller, the STM32F100RB and it kinda worked. Here is the link for my repository in case someone want to take a look.
https://github.com/felipheggaliza/TCC-Brushless-Gimbal

The problem I had with STM32F100RB is that the maximum frequency is just 24MHz. It worked well when driving one BLDC, but in my application I need to drive 3 BLDC motors plus IMU reading and Control. So then, I really want to implement this code using the TM4C123G because I think it will work better. The only thing that is annoying me is how to implement the phase shift in the TM4X123G.

I also found the same technique implemented in Arduino. It is useful to understand how SPWM works: http://www.berryjam.eu/2015/04/driving-bldc-gimbals-at-super-slow-speeds-with-arduino/

Does someone have knowledge on this? Any piece of code doing the phase shift or direct driving a BLDC motor probably will help me a lot.

Here is a sample of the code I am willing to implement using the TM4C123G. Could someone give me any directive?

```
//
// Slow and precise BLDC motor driver using SPWM and SVPWM modulation
// Part of code used from http://elabz.com/
// (c) 2015 Ignas Gramba www.berryjam.eu
//


const int EN1 = 5;
const int EN2 = 6;
const int EN3 = 7;

const int IN1 = 9;
const int IN2 = 10;
const int IN3 = 11;

const int pwmSin[] = {128, 132, 136, 140, 143, 147, 151, 155, 159, 162, 166, 170, 174, 178, 181, 185, 189, 192, 196, 200, 203, 207, 211, 214, 218, 221, 225, 228, 232, 235, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 248, 249, 250, 250, 251, 252, 252, 253, 253, 253, 254, 254, 254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 254, 254, 254, 253, 253, 253, 252, 252, 251, 250, 250, 249, 248, 248, 247, 246, 245, 244, 243, 242, 241, 240, 239, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 248, 249, 250, 250, 251, 252, 252, 253, 253, 253, 254, 254, 254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 254, 254, 254, 253, 253, 253, 252, 252, 251, 250, 250, 249, 248, 248, 247, 246, 245, 244, 243, 242, 241, 240, 239, 238, 235, 232, 228, 225, 221, 218, 214, 211, 207, 203, 200, 196, 192, 189, 185, 181, 178, 174, 170, 166, 162, 159, 155, 151, 147, 143, 140, 136, 132, 128, 124, 120, 116, 113, 109, 105, 101, 97, 94, 90, 86, 82, 78, 75, 71, 67, 64, 60, 56, 53, 49, 45, 42, 38, 35, 31, 28, 24, 21, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 21, 24, 28, 31, 35, 38, 42, 45, 49, 53, 56, 60, 64, 67, 71, 75, 78, 82, 86, 90, 94, 97, 101, 105, 109, 113, 116, 120, 124};

int currentStepA;
int currentStepB;
int currentStepC;
int sineArraySize;
int increment = 0;
boolean direct = 1; // direction true=forward, false=backward

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void setup() {

  setPwmFrequency(IN1); // Increase PWM frequency to 32 kHz  (make unaudible)
  setPwmFrequency(IN2);
  setPwmFrequency(IN3);

  pinMode(IN1, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(IN2, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(IN3, OUTPUT); 

  pinMode(EN1, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(EN2, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(EN3, OUTPUT); 


  digitalWrite(EN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(EN2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(EN3, HIGH);


  sineArraySize = sizeof(pwmSin)/sizeof(int); // Find lookup table size
  int phaseShift = sineArraySize / 3;         // Find phase shift and initial A, B C phase values
  currentStepA = 0;
  currentStepB = currentStepA + phaseShift;
  currentStepC = currentStepB + phaseShift;

  sineArraySize--; // Convert from array Size to last PWM array number
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void loop() {

  analogWrite(IN1, pwmSin[currentStepA]);
  analogWrite(IN2, pwmSin[currentStepB]);
  analogWrite(IN3, pwmSin[currentStepC]);  

  if (direct==true) increment = 1;
  else increment = -1;     

  currentStepA = currentStepA + increment;
  currentStepB = currentStepB + increment;
  currentStepC = currentStepC + increment;

  //Check for lookup table overflow and return to opposite end if necessary
  if(currentStepA > sineArraySize)  currentStepA = 0;
  if(currentStepA < 0)  currentStepA = sineArraySize;

  if(currentStepB > sineArraySize)  currentStepB = 0;
  if(currentStepB < 0)  currentStepB = sineArraySize;

  if(currentStepC > sineArraySize)  currentStepC = 0;
  if(currentStepC < 0) currentStepC = sineArraySize; 

  /// Control speed by this delay
  delay(10);

}


void setPwmFrequency(int pin) {
  if(pin == 5 || pin == 6 || pin == 9 || pin == 10) {
    if(pin == 5 || pin == 6) {
      TCCR0B = TCCR0B & 0b11111000 | 0x01;
    } else {
      TCCR1B = TCCR1B & 0b11111000 | 0x01;
    }
  }
  else if(pin == 3 || pin == 11) {
    TCCR2B = TCCR2B & 0b11111000 | 0x01;
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Feliphe

Comment: Has MCU DMAs that can be used for PWM?

Comment: Yes, from what I read the microcontroller Tiva C TM4C123G has DMAs that can be used for timing and hopefully can be used as PWM. This page has a great explanation about the DMA specs for this microcontroller. Link: https://sites.google.com/site/luiselectronicprojects/tutorials/tiva-tutorials/tiva-dma/understanding-the-tiva-dma

Comment: Then you can set it to use precalculated data to be output through DMA directly to PWM output. You can set a threshold to be waked up and fill new data into buffer.